# How to access the classes in "BOOT-INF/classes" jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring boot 2 project that creates a jar (and publish it as a artifact) but classes are in the "BOOT-INF/classes". When I include this dependency in the other project
it gives "package com.native.ultra.repo.aspect does not exist".

I tried :
a)giving classification as `<classifier>exec</classifier>`
b)tried using `<layout>MODULE</layout>` which is not supported in Spring boot 2.

Let me know what I should change in the pom of Main service so that it is able to access the classes in "BOOT-INF/classes". There are some solution to include each class in the class-path, need some help what to do here.

**1.Repository service jar :-**
Holds common type of code and utilities that is to be published as artifacts and imported as jar for the other projects.

pom.xml (of Repository service) :

```
        <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.native.ultra</groupId>
    <artifactId>repo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>Repo Service Parent POM</name>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>exec</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>${java.version}</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

**2.Main service** - I am importing the dependency of the Repo service here and want to access the utility classes but while building it(mvn clean install), it fails with "package does not exist"

pom.xml (of Main service) :

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.native.ultra</groupId>
            <artifactId>repo</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.zipkin.brave</groupId>
        <artifactId>brave</artifactId>
        <version>5.12.6</version>
    </dependency>
    
    </dependencies>
    
    <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>ultra-snapshot-local</id>
        <url>https://artifacts.native.com/ultra-snapshot-local</url>
        <snapshots/>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
```

Comment: You cannot include a Spring Boot jar as a dependency into another project due to the different structure (needed for the fat-jar with dependencies). If this is only a dependency just create a regular jar instead of let spring boot create it, if you want to use a dependency and to be a spring boot jar configure the spring boot plugin to generate 2 artifacts. All of this is [explained in the official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-an-additional-executable-jar)

Comment: @M.Deinum, I was using repo(jar) to create Trace id/Span id, logger via aspect, so using Spring boot. Let me know if thats possible without Spring boot or I should not create a jar but a dependency project ?